# Looking for a comprehensive reference about the notion of probability distribution divergence and different divergence and distribution measures

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory

I have recently started my research in GANs and have been working on it for a while now. I am looking for a good source to read about different measures of distribution divergences like Kullback-Leibler, Jensen-Shannon, Earth mover's, etc. Any suggestion?